# more space under the website without any reason

Tags: css

i've a simple html page but there's a space under the footer which I don't know where it comes from I've tried to resize the body , the wrapper and the container but the same result

```
http://mawk3y.net/alsoos/hathal/
```

Comment: Check the padding of the `<body>` tag and change the value of `padding-bottom` to 0

Comment: ... same for margin...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

get rid of the height in line 487 of style.css:

```
.copyright {
    font-family: 'GESSUniqueLight-Light';
    color: #1c2d54;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 130px;
    /* height: 120px; */
    float: left;
    margin-left: 450px;
    margin-top: 70px;
   }
```

Comment: thank you so much my mistake height should be 12 not 120

Answer (score 0):

If the answer above does not work for you you may want to try moving your footer outside of your main content wrapper and then use a sticky footer to keep its position fixed at the bottom of the page.